# Exception in replace-child DOM

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, addeventlistener, mousemove

Can anyone explain this exception in replace-child DOM “If the replacement of oldchild by newchild would lead to a cycle, that is if newchild is an ancestor of the node”
with example?

Comment: There is no way that click and other events were working unless you looped over the collection and added the listeners to each instance or did something like `btn[0].addEventListener...`

Comment: @charlietfl No bro i didn't did btn[0].addEventlistener but with btn.addEventlistener.
It was working fine on other events but not on Mouse-Move.
That is why i am also confused

Comment: You must have been using getElementById() or querySelector() to return a single element only. Read the link at top of page thoroughly

Comment: Yes thanks @charlietfl 
Issue got resolved after using (getElementbyId)